Check if the charachter frequency of two "words" are significantly different
Although the problem as in the title might sound a little odd, I have a dataset where each entry includes two "words" that include 1000 and 1100 characters respectively. For each entry, I need to find if the frequency of characters in these two words is similar or different.
Is there a kind of test like a paired t-test that I can use for this situation?

Not sure why you suggest a paired t test, as nothing is paired.
Seems to me that a simple chi-square test would be the way to go. You would have 2 rows (one for each "word", 26 columns (letters), and thus 52 cells with a total of 2100 numbers to fill in.

Thanks for the reply! When I implemented the chi-square test, it worked wonderfully for most of the entries. But in some entries, the words do not include all of the characters in the alphabet or include them less than 5 times. Is there anything I can do in these cases?

If there are a lot of cells with expected frequencies below 5, you can use Fisher's exact test. But with a 26x2 grid with thousands of numbers, it might take a long time to run. Note that it is the expected frequencies that count (not the observed). And people disagree about what "a lot" means.
